# Camera shaking/Jitters when Player moves

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I made a Camera Script that follows the player using a lerp for making it look more smooth, but for some reason, it looks laggy when walking in some sudden areas.

The ground the player is walking on is tilemap, and at first, I thought there were tiny cell gaps that caused the problem, but it still happens even when I changed the ground to one solid block. So I concluded it must be something with Camera Script that cause this problem.

Here is a video clip of what I'm talking about: https://youtu.be/mmBMHWuHpxo

I think the problem stems from this part of my camera script:

```
 void SetTargetPos()
{
    // By default the target x and y coordinates of the camera are it's current x and y coordinates.
    targetX = transform.position.x;
    targetY = transform.position.y;
    // If the player has moved beyond the x margin...
    if (CheckXMargin())
    {
        // ... the target x coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current x position and the player's current x position.
       targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, transformPlayer.position.x, xSmooth * Time.deltaTime); 

    }

    // If the player has moved beyond the y margin...
    if (CheckYMargin())
    {
        // ... the target y coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current y position and the player's current y position.
       targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, transformPlayer.position.y, ySmooth * Time.deltaTime);


    }

        // The target x and y coordinates should not be larger than the maximum or smaller than the minimum.
        targetX = Mathf.Clamp(targetX, currentMinBounds.x, currentMaxBounds.x);
        targetY = Mathf.Clamp(targetY, currentMinBounds.y, currentMaxBounds.y);
   
    
    // Set the camera's position to the target position with the same z component.
    transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);

    TestOutOfCamBounds();
}
```

Btw I have the exact same script on different Unity Projects with the same variable inputs. There is a small difference, and that just the overall size of everything in the second project is a lot smaller than the first one. But it works completely fine on that project. I have also tried Smoothdamp instead of Lerp, still no success. Here is a video clip of the other project: https://youtu.be/baJmKehYfG0

Any help will be much appreciated.

If you want to look at the entire script here it is:

```
    public class Camera_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Camera_Controller _instance;
    public static Camera_Controller instance;
    [Header("Put player here")]
    public GameObject player;
    public Transform transformPlayer;
    [Space]
    Vector2 currentMinBounds;
    Vector2 currentMaxBounds;
    public Vector3 targetPos;

    [Space]
    [Header("Camera Properties")]
    public float xMargin = 1f;
    public float yMargin = 1f;
    public float xSmooth = 8f;
    public float ySmooth = 8f;
    public Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    private float targetY;
    private float targetX;

    [Header("Smooth Transition")]
    public Vector3 oldPosition;
    public Vector3 targetPosition;
    public float transitionsTime;
    public bool switchingCamera;

    private void Awake()
    {


        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _instance = this;
        }

        instance = _instance;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        targetPos = transform.position;
    }

    private bool CheckXMargin()
    {
        // Returns true if the distance between the camera and the player in the x axis is greater than the x margin.
        return Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - transformPlayer.position.x) > xMargin;
    }


    private bool CheckYMargin()
    {
        // Returns true if the distance between the camera and the player in the y axis is greater than the y margin.
        return Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - transformPlayer.position.y) > yMargin;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (!switchingCamera)
        {
            SetTargetPos();
        }

    }


    public void SetCamBounds(Vector2 minBounds, Vector2 maxBounds) //Called from Game Events Trough WarpController as trigger
    {
        currentMinBounds = minBounds;
        currentMaxBounds = maxBounds;
    }
    //SetTargetPos() should be causing the problem
    void SetTargetPos()
    {
        // By default the target x and y coordinates of the camera are it's current x and y coordinates.
        targetX = transform.position.x;
        targetY = transform.position.y;
        // If the player has moved beyond the x margin...
        if (CheckXMargin())
        {
            // ... the target x coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current x position and the player's current x position.
           targetX = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, transformPlayer.position.x, xSmooth * Time.deltaTime); 

        }

        // If the player has moved beyond the y margin...
        if (CheckYMargin())
        {
            // ... the target y coordinate should be a Lerp between the camera's current y position and the player's current y position.
           targetY = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, transformPlayer.position.y, ySmooth * Time.deltaTime);


        }

            // The target x and y coordinates should not be larger than the maximum or smaller than the minimum.
            targetX = Mathf.Clamp(targetX, currentMinBounds.x, currentMaxBounds.x);
            targetY = Mathf.Clamp(targetY, currentMinBounds.y, currentMaxBounds.y);
       
        
        // Set the camera's position to the target position with the same z component.
        transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);

        TestOutOfCamBounds();
    }

    void TestOutOfCamBounds() //Set Camera some boundaries.
    {
        if (targetPos.x <= currentMinBounds.x)
        {
            targetPos.x = currentMinBounds.x;
        }
        if (targetPos.x >= currentMaxBounds.x)
        {
            targetPos.x = currentMaxBounds.x;
        }
        if (targetPos.y <= currentMinBounds.y)
        {
            targetPos.y = currentMinBounds.y;
        }
        if (targetPos.y >= currentMaxBounds.y)
        {
            targetPos.y = currentMaxBounds.y;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the call for the cammer movement in Late update, Example bellow.

```
private void LateUpdate() {
    SetTargetPos();
}
```

This is called after the update method and might help reduce the cammer jitter.

Answer (score 1):

Your second video is 2d and your first is 3d. try lerping the z position also.

```
targetZ = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.z, transformPlayer.position.z, zSmooth * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Thank you! Sure to try it as soon I'm done with school.
But the thing I don't understand, how do you know that it is 3D? All the sprites and objects in the first project are 2D, and I even made the project using the Unity 2D template

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to it all!
I changed the update function to LateUpdate()... Sorry for wasting your time